# Python about Regular HTML

Tags: python

Here  I would like to use Python to get a page generated by JS.
This is the part of result of its return：
`Artery.addItem(Artery.cfg_jqPanel24b19_AcloneA_61567_AcloneA_86843,Artery.cfg_jqNumericc732d_AcloneA_fc477_AcloneA_16317);Artery.cfg_jqTextArea55100_AcloneA_25f4d_AcloneA_c015e={\"allowBlank\":false,\"dataName\":\"I want to get the content\",\"id\":\"jqTextArea55100_AcloneA_25f4d_AcloneA_c015e\",\"fetchFormid\":true,\"maxLengt`

Then I use regular expressions to match what I want：

```
 request=urllib.request.Request(weekurl,postdata,headers)
 result_html=opener.open(request).read().decode('utf-8')
 print(result_html)
 weekly=re.findall(r'dataName\":\"(.*?)\",\"id\":',result_html,re.DOTALL)
 print(weekly)
```

But it prints out [], why is this?
Then I tried the following code

```
import re 
s="""AcloneA_2dd40={\"allowBlank\":false,\"dataName\":\"我想要的方案\",\"id
\":\"jqTextArea55100_Aclon。。。"""
x=re.findall(r'dataName\":\"(.*?)\",\"id\":',s,re.DOTALL)
print(x)
```

it was working,what i missing? think it may be because the crawl html contains a space。

Comment: I believe you are facing an issue with encoding.. try doing a `import chardet; chardet.detect('ఆకలి')` It should show
`{'confidence': 0.938125, 'language': '', 'encoding': 'utf-8'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue by fluke, or so I think. I observed a wierd character at the *very* end of your question `space。`. The character `。`. If I try to find the encoding for it

```
>>> chardet.detect(c)
{'confidence': 0.73, 'language': '', 'encoding': 'Windows-1252'}
```

So I *guess* you've `Windows-1252` encoded stream of characters with you(not 100% sure). If so the below should resolve.

```
result_html=opener.open(request).read().encode('Windows-1252').decode('utf-8')
```

Am not sure though, as it is a guess from one character I found at the end of your question.

Comment: think u ,but I try it and AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode',I can print it in the correct format by utf-8 ，I would like to get the contents of the Chinese, is not the code should be gb213

Comment: hey, in that case you should do `text.decode('utf-8').encode('Windows-1252').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: if that works then I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: thinks,but it error with nicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2059-2062: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Were you able to `chardet.detect(c)` on the stream of bytes that you are getting as input? also can you update the question with exact output from `print(result_html)`

Comment: it was {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99}

Comment: it was {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99}

Comment: Can you also update the question with output of `print(result_html)`

Comment: That's too much, I'm pasting a part

Answer (score 0):

I know how to solve it

   `re.findall(r'dataName\\":\\"(.*?)\\",\\"id\\":',result_html,re.DOTALL)`

Just Double slash.Thanks All